# How can I delete a directory called ";"(semicolon)?

Tags: bash, rm

On a shared machine somehow a directory `;` (with a lot of stuff in it) was created.

I only have shell access to this machine and so I can't use any GUI File explorer to delete that file.

```
rm -rf ;
```

results in strange behavior since the semicolon probably acts as a command separator and is not evaluated as the directory's name.

> rm -rf ./;
> rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping './'

rm: refusing to remove '.' or '..' directory: skipping './'

Furthermore I do not want to delete other directories and so I am not willing to play around with wildcards and stuff.

How can I securely remove that semicolon-directory recursivly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote its name. Quoting the name will stop the shell from interpreting it as a command terminator.

```bash
rm -rf ';'
```

The same goes for working with files with names containing other characters that the shell usually treat specially, like filename globbing characters, `&`, `<`, `>`, `(`, `)`, `{`, `}`, newlines, tabs, spaces, etc., and any other character that may be part of the shell's grammar.

Comment: More on that at [How to use a special character as a normal one in Unix shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/296141)

Comment: I was sure this would be a dup but my search-foo failed me

Comment: OK. Thanks. I solved it with `find . -name "*;*" -exec rm -rf {} \;` now. But yours work too. I think I tried this and it didnt work but I could produce it now with `mkdir ';'`

Answer (score 0):

when I have a hard time deleting a directory I download the tool mc(midnight commander), it's a tool that is very similar to Norton Commander and has great functions and GUI that you can use to delete problematic directories

try

```
yum install mc -y
```

in the command line after the installation write just

```
mc
```